# Regarding ProductList View URL

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In customization Page Once the user edits or adds products and hits save, the tab would close and they would be on the product list view of the order.In short How to get Url of product list view of the order and set into button control in another page?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the requirements here.  You want to put a list view of products related to an order on a form?  what form?  is there a reason a sub-grid won't work?

Comment: Hi Joseph Duty, Thanks for help. I have created one button in salesorder entity. when I click on that button at that time new custom form open. On that form when I click on close button at that page is redirect in view of product list page.   so how can I get the url of product list view in crm and set into close button control?